# How to nest the form of a rich many to many associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

**Update to prevent any more wrong answers:**

- A product has many product images
- There are many products and many scenes
- A product has one image for each scene, to make the product image fit that scene

---

**Original question:**

I have two tables (Scenes and Products) with a rich many to many relation through a third table (ProductImages). ProductImages has one three fields: scene_id, product_id and image. Now I want to nest a form for an instance of ProductImage within the Product form for each Scenes entity.

So, when I'd have three Scenes, I want to show three "image" fields within in each Product form. The three fields should always be displayed, even if the relation does not yet exist.

Can someone please tell me how to do this? I have the relations defined correct (I think), and I'm using the Paperclip plugin for the image attachment.

---

**Update**

To clarify what my models look like, here's the idea:

```
Scenes:
| id | name      | background-image   |
|----|-----------|--------------------|
| 1  | kitchen x | a picture          |
| 2  | kitchen y | an other picture   |
| 3  | kitchen z | just other picture |

Products:
| id | name         | price | material |
|----|--------------|-------|----------|
| 1  | countertop x | 100   | wood     |
| 2  | countertop y | 33    | metal    |
| 3  | tap x        | 95    | chrome   |

ProductImages:
| id | product | scene | image     |
|----|---------|-------|-----------|
| 1  | 1       | 1     | some pic  |
| 2  | 1       | 2     | good pic  |
| 3  | 1       | 3     | weird pic |
| 4  | 2       | 1     | a pic     |
| 5  | 2       | 2     | one pic   |
| 6  | 2       | 3     | other pic |
```

And my goal is to nest the form for the ProductImages image field inside the products form.

I also added this method to the `products_controller.rb`. "ep" Is the product that is about to be edited; this method is called at the beginning of the edit method.

```
def check_relation_with_scenes(ep)
    Scene.all.each do |s|
        ProductImage.find_or_create_by_product_id_and_scene_id(:product_id => ep.id, :scene_id => s.id)
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what a `scene` actually is? Is it the setting (a photograph) a product is shown in? And then the extra image in the `ProductImages` table is then a close-up? Or some kind of possible example usage? If I understand correctly, for each scene it should be possible to upload a photo: correct?

Comment: A scene is indeed a photo, in which multiple products are shown at the same time. The extra images are not close-ups. Each scene has a different photo, in which the angle might be different, and the lightning. So to show the same product correctly in each scene, indeed there is a photo of each product for each scene.

Comment: Please show us the ruby code of the three related models and the relations between them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit, these associations feel very strange and would personally make rethink my design; I'm guessing this is the reason there haven't been many responses to your question.  Regardless, I think this is more the gist of what you're looking for:

models/scene.rb

```
 class Scene < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_images
   has_many :products, :through=>:product_images
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
 end
```

models/product.rb

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_images
   has_many :scenes, :through=>:product_images
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images
 end
```

models/product_image.rb

```
 class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :scene
   belongs_to :product
 end
```

I've assumed that scene is your 'parent' form and the products are nested in each scene -- and each product has a product_image form.

views/scenes/_form.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for @scene do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_messages %>
   <p>
     <%= f.label :name %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </p>
   <p>
     <%= f.label :background_image %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :background_image %>
   </p>
   <fieldset><legend>Products</legend>  
    <%= f.fields_for :products do |product_form| %>
     <%= render :partial=>"/products/form", :locals => { :f => product_form } %>
    <% end %>
   </fieldset>

   <p><%= f.submit %></p>
 <% end %>
```

views/products/_form.html.erb

```
  <p>
   <%= f.label :name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :price %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :material %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :material %>
  </p>

  <fieldset><legend>Product Images</legend>
   <%= f.fields_for :product_images do |pi_form| %>
    <%= render :partial=>"/product_images/form", :locals => { :f => pi_form } %>
   <% end %>
  </fieldset>
```

views/product_images/_form.html.erb

```
 <p>
  <%= f.hidden_field :scene_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :product_id %>
 </p>

 <p>
  <%= f.label :image %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :image %>
 </p>
```

controllers/scenes_controller.rb

```
def new
 @scene = Scene.new
 3.times do
  @scene.products.build.product_images.build
 end
end

def create
 @scene = Scene.new(params[:scene])
 if @scene.save
   redirect_to @scene, :notice => "Successfully created scene."
 else
   render :action => 'new'
 end
end
```

I also noticed in your table defs that the product_images table shows 'scene' and 'product' columns. Probably just a typo, but the columns should likely be scene_id and product_id respectively.  Good luck!

Comment: Well the products form doesn't need to be nested in scenes perse, appart from that your answer might be correct, I'll give it a go! And it wasn't a typo, I was just saving a little space xD Indeed I'm using _id.

Comment: Any suggestions on doing this better are welcome btw, with my expertise I couldn't come up with a better way to do this than the current design.

Comment: Hmm, this gives me a `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicSourceError (nice one), "Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Scene#products' on the polymorphic object 'Product#product'"`. I can't seem to figure it out... It's gone as soon as I remove `accepts_nested_attributes_for :products` from it's gone.

Comment: I spun my quick dirty example up in Rails v 3.1.3 -- but I don't think that should matter.  There might be some other conflict in your associations causing this.  Not sure if it's acceptable, but if so, I can send you my simple project via public dropbox or email so you can tinker.

Comment: Yes I had that set that polymorphic property myself somewhere along the way, buy had forgotten about that. Your answer turned out to be the right one! Thank you so much! Before I let go of the 100 point's, I wanna make sure this works as I expected, but I'm sure it will be fine!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help and I hope it works out.  The only question mark I have is the use of the hidden fields in the product_images partial.  They're probably not necessary but I didn't experiment too much with it.  I'm guessing there will be other tweaks but I think you've got enough to start with.  Good luck!

Comment: True, works without it too. I'm going to change it anyway, don't want to nest the product form in the scenes form, but like this it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want the link table to hold the image information? It looks like the images are specific to the Scenes i.e each Scene has an image.

**models/scene.rb**

```
class Scene < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products_scenes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :products_scences     

  has_attached_file :scene_image, :path => "../uploads/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", :url => "../uploads/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"

end
```

**models/products_scenes.rb**

```
class ProductsScenes < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :scene

end
```

**models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products_scenes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :scenes, :through => :products_scenes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scenes, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

**controller/product_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.scenes.build
  end
end
```

**views/product/_form.hmtl.haml**

```
= form_for(@product) do |f|
  = render @product.scenes
    = link_to "Add", "#add", :id => "add-scene"
```

**views/scenes/_scene.html.haml**

```
= fields_for "product[scenes_attributes][]", scene do |scene_form|
  %li.scene_list
    .left_field
      = scene_form.label :scene_image
    .right_field
      = scene_form.file_field :scene_image
    %span.right_action_negative
      = link_to("Remove", "#delete", :class => "delete-scene")
```

**public/javascripts/application.js**

```
  $('a#add-scene').click(function() {
    $('#scene_list li:first').clone().find('input').val('').end().appendTo('#scene_list');
  });

  $('.delete-scene').live('click', function() {
    if ($('#scene_list li').length > 1)
         $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        else
         alert('No scenes listed.');
  });
```

Comment: No I really think I need to use the link table, I've updated my question, maybe that will help.

Comment: Ok, you'r answer wasn't the one, but it did help me think in the right direction, thus I find it to be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of code you've posted. I think it would be best to direct you to the following Railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3

They should surely help you solve your issue and bring you much closer to cracking a beer.

Comment: The railscasts unfortunately don't discuss the situation I've described, I had already watched them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the following model structure, here is the solution for your problem:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products_images  
  has_many :scenes, :through => :products_images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products_images
end

class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :scene
end

class Scene < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products_images
end
```

in your controller

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  (3-@product.products_images.size).times {@product.products_images.build} if @product.products_images.size < 3
  #ensure always have at least 3 product_images initialized
end
```

in your form.

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :product_images do |pf| %>
    <%= pf.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.